# UIWebView - how to support HTTPs,Untrusted sites and sites with popup authentication

Tags: ios, https, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm building an app with UIWebView.
I want to support both HTTPS, untrusted sites and sites with popup authentication.

I tried this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11664147/2445225

but it's giving me support for only https sites.

I tried also the posts:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14286789/2445225

It looks like this is not possible to support all kind of sites in UIWebView.

Is it possible to support both Https sites, Untrusted sites and sites that have popup authentication?

Comment: How can i differentiate between these cases? Can you help me with code please?

Comment: I found a way to differentiate between server trust and basic authentication. How can I differentiate between trusted and untrusted sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. Not so good but a way.
Needs to check for every request for the protectionSpace on willSendRequestForAuthentication and behave accordingly.